# Trying to load optionals saved in NSUserDefaults via AppDelegate always returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a Settings class that has a bunch of `UITextField` properties, each of which I'm casting to a Decimal variable. That part all works and I'm using `NSUserDefaults` to save the `UITextField` contents and the variable Decimals. The Settings view controller properly loads and displays the `UITextField` content I previously save.

The problem is that I need to access the optional variables without the Settings view controller loading and when I attempt to load them via the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`, it always returns nil. If I load the variables (from `NSUserDefaults`) in `viewDidLoad()` or what not on the actual Settings view controller, the value shows up correctly.

I'm still pretty new to Swift, but any ideas what I'm overlooking here?

Edit: I apologize for the delay; just got back into town and I have attached the code that covers my issues. I have quite a few more variables I'm wanting to assign but once I figure it out for one, the rest will be easy.

As of now, I can't even get the variable values to load from the view controller. I know that when I edit the text field the respective `Decimal?` variable changes along with it, it just doesn't get saved or loaded. The `UITextField`s that I'm saving to `NSUserDefaults` are savings/loading properly, just not the `Decimal?` variables that feed from the `UITextField` values.

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

var concrete360v: Decimal?

@IBOutlet var concrete360: UITextField?

//save the text field values to NSUserDefaults
func saveTextField(textField: String?, key: String) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(textField, forKey: key)
}

//load text field value saved to NSUserDefault
func loadDefault(textField: UITextField?, fieldName: String) {
    if let text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: fieldName) as? String 
{
        textField?.text = text
    }
}

//assign the text field values to their respective value variables
func assignTextToValue(textField: UITextField?, valueField: inout Decimal?) 
{
    if let text = textField?.text {
        valueField = Decimal(string: text)
        print("\(String(describing: concrete360v))")
    }
}

//save the value variable to NSUserDefaults
func saveValue(value: Decimal?, key: String) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(value, forKey: key)
}

//load value variable from NSUserDefaults
func loadValue(value: inout Decimal?, valueName: String) {
    if let loadedValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: valueName) as? Decimal {  
        value = loadedValue
    }
}

//save ALL value variables to NSUserDefaults
func saveAllValues() {
    saveValue(value: concrete360v, key: "concrete360v")
    print("Saved all your variables")
}

//load ALL value variables from NSUserDefaults
func loadAllValues() {
    loadValue(value: &concrete360v, valueName: "concrete360v")
    print("\(String(describing: concrete360v))")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    loadDefault(textField: concrete360, fieldName: "concrete360")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    loadValue(value: &concrete360v, valueName: "concrete360v")
    print("\(String(describing: concrete360v))")
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: My apologies, just got back into town and updated with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CFPreferences`/`UserDefaults` system on macOS and iOS is able to store only a few types of objects. Since the actual implementation for the `UserDefaults` class is in Objective-C (where it's named `NSUserDefaults`), these types are all Objective-C types. The type involved in reading and writing numeric values to and from the defaults system is called `NSNumber`, which is basically just an object-oriented wrapper around C's primitive integer and floating-point types. Most Swift integer and floating types can be cast to `NSNumber` via the Swift<->Objective-C bridging magic, which is why you can just send something like an `Int` or a `Double` to `UserDefaults`'s methods and expect it to work. However, `Decimal` is a little different, because it bridges to Objective-C as `NSDecimalNumber`, which is a *subclass* of `NSNumber`. Since it conforms to `NSNumber`'s API, `UserDefaults` is able to write the value to the defaults system; however, the underlying storage for the defaults system does not keep the original class, but rather just writes the numeric value. Therefore, if you write `1.23` as a `Decimal`, the number `1.23` will be written, but then when you read it back, `UserDefaults` will see `1.23` in the storage, and import it as a garden-variety `NSNumber`, probably wrapping a `Double`.

You can see this if you run a little test:

```
import Foundation

let foo = 2.3 as Decimal

UserDefaults.standard.set(foo, forKey: "Foo")

print(type(of: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Foo")!))
```

This outputs:

```
__NSCFNumber
```

which is a private subclass of `NSNumber` (which exists to facilitate the toll-free bridging between `NSNumber` and `CFNumberRef`, but that's beyond the scope of this answer).

Anyway, `NSNumber` magically bridges to most of the standard Swift integer and floating-point types, but the system doesn't have magic to bridge it to `Decimal`. You can cast an `NSDecimalNumber` to `Decimal`, but try it with a plain old `NSNumber`, and you get `nil`. Welcome to the wild, wooly world of the Swift<->Objective-C bridge.

Anyway, you can still get this into a `Decimal` by converting instead of casting:

```
import Foundation

let foo = 2.3 as Decimal

UserDefaults.standard.set(foo, forKey: "Foo")

if let bar = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Foo") as? Double {
    let baz = Decimal(bar)
    print("got baz: \(baz)")
} else {
    print("bar is nil")
}
```

outputs:

```
got baz: 2.3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation. I'm really trying to understand _why_ things work rather than just how to get them to work the way I want. So it seems like bridging is still limited between Objective-C and Swift and that may become irrelevant if Apple writes those frameworks in Swift at some point. I will try this code tonight when I'm back on my Mac. As far as savings/loading to/from `NSUserDefaults`, does my code look correct? I know I'm using an `inout` parameter which I hadn't before.